# Returning defined type from Either

Tags: haskell

I have the following type declared:

```
data Property = Property {mapProperty :: !Object
                      } deriving (Show, Generic)
```

I am returning that type from the following function:

```
parseProps :: String -> IO (Either String Property)
parseProps m = fmap property <$> (eitherDecode <$> getMap m)
```

In the calling function, I have the following:

```
pr <- liftIO $ parseProps t
let pro = case pr of
        Left err -> fail err
        Right pr -> pr
```

I get the following error from the line above (Right pr -> pr):

Couldn't match expected type ‘m a’ with actual type ‘Property’
• In the expression: pr
  In a case alternative: Right pr -> pr
  In the expression:

```
    case pr of {
      Left err -> fail err
      Right pr -> pr }
```

• Relevant bindings include
    pro :: m a (bound at src/Actor/Master.hs:42:7)

I appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Your `case` expression has branches with different types.
`fail` has the type `Monad m => String -> m a` (so `fail err` has type `Monad m => m a`) and `pr` is a `Property`.

That's how it gets `m a` not matching `Property`.

If you want them to match you need to turn the `Property` into `m Property` with `return`.

Like so:

```
pr <- liftIO $ parseProps t
pro <- case pr of
    Left err -> fail err
    Right pr -> return pr
...
```

And do the stuff with `pro`

Also, as Jon Purdy, and Paul Johnson pointed out in the comments, there is a combinator for this operation called `either`. So this is a cleaner way to write that:

```
pr <- liftIO $ parseProps t
pro <- either fail return pr
```

Comment: This can also be written more succinctly with the `either` combinator, e.g.: `pro <- either fail pure pr`

Comment: @JonPurdy Or `pro <- either fail return pr`. Beginners may not know that `pure == return`.

Comment: @PaulJohnson: Oops, yeah, force of habit there. I always use `pure` nowadays because it’s slightly more general (`Applicative` instead of `Monad`) and I just like the name better—`pure x` converts a pure value `x` into an action (which for most monads does just “return” `x`), whereas `return x` is a *faux ami* of the `return` keyword for exiting (early) from a procedure in an imperative language.